# Dynamic programming :how to solve all combination ordered coin change problem for large input

Tags: algorithm, dynamic

I have a challenge to find number of ways to get a sum of a given number from an array containing coins. For example:

coins: {2,3,5,7}
sum: 8
total ways: 6 -> (2 + 2 + 2 + 2), (2 + 3 + 3), (3 + 2 + 3), (3 + 3 + 2), (3 + 5), and (5 + 3).

I have the solution that works using dp pseudo code:

```
build an array ar of size "sum"
ar[0]=1
for i = 1 to sum do:
    ar[i]=ar[i-2]+ar[i-3]+ar[i-5]+ar[i-7]
return ar[sum]
```

As mentioned this code works fine, but the platform I am running this in can have sum as large as 10<sup>19</sup>, and as expected it gives me a timeout. Is there any other way this can be dealt with? I have even tried to reduce the size of the array when it goes beyond size `i-largest value in coins`. But that as well times out.

Comment: Study https://ronzii.wordpress.com/2011/07/09/using-matrix-exponentiation-to-calculated-nth-fibonacci-number/.  Writing the transitions as a matrix and repeatedly squaring it will be a lot faster.

Comment: Not sure if that will work. Even if I can come up with such matrix multiplication formula, I will still need to multiply the matrix 10^19 times. And from what I have seen even a no op loop of that long will timeout